# different form state redirects in a hook_form_alter

Tags: 7, forms

i have the code in template.php:

```
THEMENAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'answer_node_form' && !isset($form['nid']['#value'])) {
    //dpm($form);
    // redirect after we created a new node
    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'node_reference_redirect';
  } elseif ($form_id == 'answer_node_form' && isset($form['nid']['#value'])) {
    // redirect after we have made changes to a node - node/17/edit
    $form['#submit'][] = 'node_save_reference_redirect';
  }
}

function node_reference_redirect($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'node/' . arg(1);
}

function node_save_reference_redirect($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['redirect'] = '/index.php';//$form['field_answer']['und'][0]['nid']['#default_value'];
}
```

function named node_reference_redirect() works as expected - it redirects after creating a new node: node/add/content-type, but the 2nd redirect - when we are doing changes to an existing node: node/[nid]/edit, when we press "save" it doesn't redirects to a index.php for example... Can't figure out what's wrong. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Well, everything in Drupal runs through index.php. If the redirect works and doesn't start with a forward slash, why start index.php with a slash? Try just redirecting to a basic page or $base_url variable.

Comment: Tried redirect to a node/1 == no redirects :(

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like:

```
$form['#redirect'] = $base_url';
```

you are missing '#' in both of the forms.

Comment: In my case its $form_state['redirect'].